# Printing an arrowhead of stars using nested for loops

Tags: java

Print an arrowhead.
Let the user input how big the arrow should be by entering the total number of lines to draw.
The user entered 9 in the example below. Prompt the user to enter an odd number only.
It should model this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
    int i, j, numRows;
    Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many rows would you like the triangle to have?");
    numRows=reader.nextInt();
    //row
    for(i=1;i<=numRows;i++){
        //column
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print("*");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

this is the top half. i can make the bottom half by altering the nested loop.  I know that I need to  have the nested loop decrease the amount of stars after it reaches the middle column, or (i/2)+1, but I am not sure how to do this.  I tried using an if statement with j-- inside of the column loop but either that is not correct or I made a mistake.

Comment: This should probably go on code review site?

Comment: @PressingOnAlways - does not seem so, since it's **not** a fully functional program.

Answer (score 0):

put this  for bottom half:

```
for(i=numRows;i>=0;i--){
        for(j=i-1;j>0;j--){
            System.out.print("*");

        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two nested loops similar to what you have now. Think about what starting value the inner loop should use and what the condition of the loop should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i, j, numRows;
int modifier=1;
Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many rows would you like the triangle to have?");
numRows=reader.nextInt();
//row
for(i=1;i>0;){
    //column
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
        System.out.print("*");

    }
    System.out.println();

    if (i == numRows) {
        modifier=-1;
    }
    i=i+modifier;
}
```

I really shouldn't be doing your homework... but i always get sucked into these questions cuz they're trivial and sorta fun for me to solve...

My professors would always think I was strange because I never answered the problem the most straight-forward manner. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printStarArrow() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int numRows = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out
            .println("How many rows would you like the triangle to have?");
    numRows = reader.nextInt();
    if (numRows <= 0 || numRows % 2 != 1) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an odd number only.");
        return;
    }
    // row
    for (i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        if (i <= (numRows / 2) + 1)
            j = i;
        else
            j = --j;
        printStar(j);
    }
}

public static void printStar(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```